# How can I get the largest, and smallest number from a list using LINQ, without using Min() Max()?

Tags: c#, linq, geo

I've been working on an application that generates Latitudes and Longitudes, and I now require the ability to find the largest and smallest values to determine the upper and lower limits (and east / west limits) of the data set.

I've been trying to sort them using the Enumerable.Min method, but it should appear to not support numbers below -100.0000.

Have I made a mistake with my code? How can get the largest and smallest numbers in the most efficient way (lists have around 150,000+ entries).

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new string[]{"-88.98559", "-94.98711", "-95.79591", "-98.04622", "100.0001", "-101.57691", "-110.00614"};
        var arrList = new List<string>(){};

        foreach (var value in arr)
        {
            arrList.Add(value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(arrList.Min().ToString()); //Result : 100.0001, should be -110.00614
        Console.WriteLine(arrList.Max().ToString()); //Result : -98.04622
    }
```

Comment: Your arrList contains strings!

Comment: Ugh, of course. Thanks! That is so dumb of me.

Comment: To answer the title: see OrderBy ;-) Titles should reflect the *ACTUAL* issue which is further clarified/supported in the body.

Answer (score 1):

looks like your problem is that you're using min/max on string values.  if you're comparing the string "100" vs "90" then "100" is smaller because 1 < 9.  (no different than "alice" vs "bob".  a < b even though "bob" is shorter)
if you want to do numeric comparisons, then you have to make arrList an array of floats or something, and `float.parse(value)` before you add to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the simple answer was to store my values as doubles (and adjust my generating code to not convert to string). Thanks all for the nudge!

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new double[]{-88.98559, -94.98711, -95.79591, -98.04622, 100.0001, -101.57691, -110.00614};
        var arrList = new List<double>(){};

        foreach (var value in arr)
        {
            arrList.Add(value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(arrList.Min().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(arrList.Max().ToString());
    }
```